# SQLAlchemy - Adding where clauses to a select generates subquery

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

The [docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/core/selectable.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.Select.where) for `Select.where` say that this method is supposed to append a `WHERE` clause to the existing SELECT query, but sometimes it seems to wrap the select as a subquery, resulting in a `ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) subquery in FROM must have an alias` error.  This only seems to happen when the select I'm trying to filter had a join earlier in the query chain

```
# this works
my_select = select([tbl.c.id, tbl.c.my_col])
filtered = my_select.where(tbl.c.my_col == 'foo')

# this doesn't work, and seems to wrap the my_select in an additional subquery
j = tbl1.join(tbl2, tbl1.c.id == tbl2.c.id)
my_select = select([tbl1.c.id, tbl2.c.my_col]).select_from(j)
filtered = my_select.where(my_select.c.my_col == 'foo')

# Text representations will usually work as expected
j = tbl1.join(tbl2, tbl1.c.id == tbl2.c.id)
my_select = select([tbl1.c.id, tbl2.c.my_col]).select_from(j)
filtered = my_select.where("my_col = 'foo'")
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I just figured this out.  The problem seems to be the self referential column, so

```
filtered = my_select.where(my_select.c.my_col == 'foo')
```

Should instead be

```
filtered = my_select.where(tbl2.c.my_col == 'foo')
```

so that it refers to the original column object instead of the column in the select.

This is just a hypothesis, so would appreciate if someone else could verify as well.